# how we can count items by id in database using laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5.1

count items by id in sub category table

```
$count = DB::table('sub_category')
               ->select count(*) as 
               ->where('cat_id', $id)
```

error show

> FatalErrorException in BasicController.php line 51:
>
> syntax error, unexpected 'count' (T_STRING)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should try this. Laravel Query builders provide [Aggregates](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/queries#aggregates)

```
$count = DB::table('sub_category')->where('cat_id', $id)->count();
```

If you still want to go for raw queries,

```
DB::table('sub_category')
                 ->select(DB::raw('count(*) as category_count'))
                 ->where('cat_id', $id)
                 ->get();
```

Comment: added comment for raw query as well, you can accept the answer.